# XML not loading in Flash

Tags: xml, actionscript

I built an image gallery in Flash and it loads the XML just fine locally, but not when I put it on the server.  I have tried putting the XML file into the directory with the SWF, as well as in all subdirectories, and it simply will not load.  The structure has a main SWF load smaller SWF modules.  The module is the gallery.  Again, it works offline, but not on the server.  The host is aplus.net.  It is on the same domain, so I don't think it is a crossdomain issue.  Can anybody help?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file name is capitalised oddly.  Have you checked that it is exactly correct?  Apache servers are case sensitive, so if your local server is not, it would explain the problem.

Comment: What happens if you browser to the xml file directly in your browser?

Comment: This was it.  I had the SWF looking for "imgDATA.xml" and it was named "imgDATA.XML", and just wasn't showing up on my local file.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is your remote folder structure the same as the local one? Have you tried putting in an absolute path?

Comment: The file structure should be irrelevant, since the XML file is always in the same folder.

The path is just "imgDATA.XML" and is in the same directory as the SWF file.  I have not tried an absolute path, unless the previous counts